# Reverse string without StringBuilder in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

As personal practice i decided to search online for common interview questions asked, and came across a seemingly simple one in which i am asked to reverse a string. My code below works but fails to print the first character..

```
static void iterative(String s){

    char[] norm = s.toCharArray();
    char [] rev = new char[norm.length];

    System.out.print("\nIteratively:  ");

    for(int i=norm.length-1; i > 0; i--){

        System.out.print(norm[i]);
    }

}
```

eg input: Hello

output: olle

Also could someone please explain why my IDE complained before adding the static keyword to my function?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Look at that -------> `i > 0` more closely.

Comment: Put `i>=0` instead of `i>0` in your for loop. Otherwise you miss off the first character, which is at index zero.

Comment: You will need to post the code that calls the method for us to determine why `static` was necessary; most likely you are calling from a `static` method such as `main`.

Comment: Your IDE complains about missing the `static` keyword, most probably because you are calling your `iterative` method from a static method in the same class (the `main` method). Is it?

Comment: "My code below works" - Are you sure, you do not reverse the string, just print it in reverse order.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: @user3160152 Can you show the codes where you call `iterative()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void iterative(String s){
   char[] norm = s.toCharArray();
   System.out.print("\nIteratively:  ");
   for(int i=norm.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
       System.out.print(norm[i]);
   }
```

Your for loop needs modification. You have count till index 0.

If you are calling this method from a static context, it should be preceded by static. Eg: If you are calling from main, as main method is always static, this should be static too.

Comment: What is the purpose of `rev`?

Comment: I just copied code from above.

Answer (score 1):

This loop of yours:

```
for(int i=norm.length-1; i > 0; i--)
```

will loop `length -1` times.

Which means if your string is `hello` with length of `5`. It will only loop `4` times. To loop once more, you may do this:

```
for(int i=norm.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

java arrays starts from `0` to `length-1` so you need to go till `0`

```
static void iterative(String s){

char[] norm = s.toCharArray();
char [] rev = new char[norm.length];

System.out.print("\nIteratively:  ");

for(int i=norm.length-1; i >= 0; i--){

    System.out.print(norm[i]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the characters in reverse, make a helper method for reversing a string.
A standalone reusable helper method is, well, reuable, and it can be unit tested.

Basically, extract the `char[]`, reverse the characters in the array, and construct a new string from the result.

To reverse the characters in the array, simply swap first and last character, then second and second-last character, and so on until you get to the middle.

```
private static String reverse(String input) {
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = chars.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        char tmp = chars[i];
        chars[i] = chars[j];
        chars[j] = tmp;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```